# How to update Label widget each time Button is clicked using TkInter - Python

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So I am trying to build a simple **calculator** that displays the number pi i.e., 3.14 in Label and each time the button 'click me' is clicked **it adds a another decimal  value to the 3.14.** For example, once clicked the Label would display 3.141, second time: 3.1415 etc etc.

Here is the code:

```
# Import the Tkinter functions
from Tkinter import *


# Create a window
loan_window = Tk()

loan_window.geometry('{}x{}'.format(500, 100))

# Give the window a title
loan_window.title('Screeen!')

## create the counter
pi_num = 3.14

# NUMBER frame
frame = Frame(loan_window, width=100, height=50)
frame.pack()

def addPlaceValue():

    pi_num= 3.14
    return pi_num


## create a label and add it onto the frame
display_nums = Label(frame, text = 'pi_num')
display_nums.pack()


#### create a label and add it onto the frame
##display_nums = Label(frame, text = pi_num)
##display_nums.pack()
##

# Create a button which starts the calculation when pressed
b1 = Button(loan_window, text = 'Click me', command= addPlaceValue, takefocus = False)
b1.pack()



# Bind it 
loan_window.bind('<Return>', addPlaceValue())


# event loop
loan_window.mainloop()
```

I've tried many times to keep track of the button clicks, but failed to do so. I see one issue; the code doesn't know which n-th time a button is clicked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you have `pi` stored for the number of digits.... But, here's one way to specify the precision very easily (let's say a precision of 100):

```
from sympy import mpmath
mpmath.dps = 100 #number of digits
PI = str(mpmath.pi)
```

The PI is a constant instance and isn't naturally subscriptable, so we convert it to a `str` for later indexing.

Now, as for updating the text we can keep track of a counter each time the button is placed.

We can set this counter as an attribute to `loan_window` with a default of `4` to display the most common representation of pi `3.14` then increment and change the label text:

Edit: When binding you also want to just pass the function name instead of `function_name()` this is actually calling the function

```
import sympy, Tkinter as tk

sympy.mpmath.dps = 100
PI = str(sympy.mpmath.pi)

loan_window = tk.Tk()
loan_window.counter = 4

frame = tk.Frame(loan_window, width=100, height=50)
frame.pack()

def addPlaceValue():

    loan_window.counter += 1
    display_nums['text'] = PI[:loan_window.counter]

display_nums = tk.Label(frame, text = PI[:loan_window.counter])
display_nums.pack()

b1 = tk.Button(loan_window, text = 'Click me', command= addPlaceValue, takefocus = False)
b1.pack()

loan_window.bind('<Return>', addPlaceValue)
loan_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think, this will return an when trying to use binding as function does not have an `event` parameter